# Angular-cli proxy. POST request sent as GET

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli with proxy to send my requests to backend. My backend runs locally on port 5000 and angular application runs of default port 4200. Everything is fine for GET requests, however all my POST requests made with HttpClient are being sent as GET requests.

Other methods, like PUT, PATCH and so on works as expected.

My proxy configuration:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

If anyone could explain why that is happening and If I'm using proxy correctly, I would be grateful.

EDIT:

Request is being made with service method:

```
logout(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('api/v1/user/logout', {});
  }
```

Comment: There isn't enough information in this for us to help you. Please, include the code you are using to run the post operation.

Comment: Sorry, updated my question with request code. Request is really basic since all I wanted to achieve with it is sending a correct method. So far it's not happening.

Comment: in angular for all post request we have to send body also. here you are not adding any body. may be its creating problem. just create a variable let body = {}; and pass it as return this.http.post('api/v1/user/logout', body);  try with this @jakub

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately adding body doesn't change anything. Payload is discarded and GET request is sent.

Comment: How do you know its sending GET ?

Comment: I inspect network with Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Is a "strange thing" send a post without any data. Try send a fool data or try send a POST to localhost:5000/api/v1/user/logout not in Angular

Comment: I don't think post data is any factor in this. Empty post request are actually quite common. What is a problem is that when using angular-cli proxy, instead of POSTs I send GETs, regardless if they carry data or not.

Comment: I had the same issue, however I was trying to connect to a remote server and this server was automatically force forwarding any http requests to https, appearently it messes it up if there is no body in the POST request and it changes to a GET. I fixed it by changing the target url in my proxy config from http to https.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was really stupid apparently. All i had to do is add `/` at the end of url and request with correct method was sent...

Comment: I'm having this issue too - super weird.  i added a trailing slash to my url but no luck